# How To Input A Space in A .bat File

Tags: notepad++

I've been messing around with .bat files for awhile, however I'm still clueless whenever I try to make a program out of a .bat file like a text based game for instance, I'm limited to one word per response I'm curious if there is anyway around that all I want to do is make a proper "if" statement that can be typed out by the user without it crashing the program

rough example: "if %Messages% == Who Are You? GOTO :Answer"

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quotes around strings containing spaces:

```
if "%Messages%" == "Who Are You?" goto Answer
...
goto End
:Answer
...
:End
```